# Downcasting from NSArray to Core Data Entity fails after upgrade from Xcode-6 beta 5

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I have some issues when upgrading from Xcode-6 beta 5 to 6.0.1 (or 6.1). In the process of upgrading, I had to add a lot of exclamation marks (!) to make the code compile, but those should not pose a problem.

However, the app now crashes during usage that worked perfectly fine when compiled with Xcode-6 beta 5. The following code fails:

```
func getTeamsAsArray() -> [Team] {
    println("antal lag: " + String(self.getNumberOfTeams()))

    let fisk: [Team] = self.teams as [Team] //This fails

    return self.teams as [Team] //This too
}
```

The failure is a "https://www.google.se/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=exc_breakpoint+(code=exc_i386_bpt+subcode=0x0)&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=41AgVN-TEIHK8gfqnYGADg"

Team is a core data entity that I have extended. The code getTeamsAsArray is placed in an extension of Game, which is also a core data entity.

Game.swift starts out as

```
class Game: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var timeStamp: NSDate
@NSManaged var teams: NSArray
@NSManaged var scoreEntries: NSSet
@NSManaged var teamsOrder: [AnyObject]

@NSManaged var entryLabels: [UILabel]

}

extension Game {
    ... a lot of code.
```

(Please don't judge me on having labels in the game model, I will replace this extremely poor coding shortcut when I figure out a proper way to do it).

In the xcdatamodeld-file, all entities "Class" property are on the form AppName.ClassName (in this case AppName.Team).

I do not understand why this has changed from beta 5, and I can not find any relevant Stackoverflow (or other) answers online that solves this problem.

I have tried to add @objc(Team) to the Team-class, but it does not work, and I do not understand what it does.

I am hoping that some nomenclature has changed that I am unaware of..

Comment: Core data represents the relation as NSSet not NSArray or Array. You might have mistaken. If you are representing one to many relation to other NSManagedObject class, then it should be NSSet.

Comment: The reason for using an NSArray is that the many to many relation is ordered, I believe that they should be using an NSArray (as opposed to unordered relations that use NSSet).

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about. If the relation is ordered, then it should be NSOrderedSet as I think. I am not aware if that is represented by NSArray in swift.

Comment: Thank you, changing from NSArray to NSOrderedSet fixes my issue! I know that I read "somewhere" that NSArrays were an option to use for ordered relations, but I don't remember where..